# Synchronizing multiple requests and multiple database calls

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm currently dealing with an issue where I get duplicate key errors when I'm creating documents in my mongo database (using mongoose) in a node.js application.

## Here is the scenario

An HTTP request to update a particular user.

```
POST /process { "user": 123 }
```

**The server checks to see if the user exists. If it doesn't exist, it creates a new user, otherwise it updates the user and saves.**

```
User.findOne({ "user": 123 }, function (err, doc) {
    if (!doc) {
        doc = new User({ ... });
    }
    doc.updated = Date.now();
    doc.save(...);
}
```

There are two asynchronous calls `findOne` and `save`. The problem I'm facing is what happens when a second HTTP request (for the same user) comes in during one of the asynchronous calls (i.e. before `doc.save` has completed for the first request. Even though node.js is single threaded, this can still occur if there is some delay during the asynchronous I/O.

```
R1: POST /process
R1: findOne => async
R2: POST /process
R2: findOne => async
R1: !doc = true
R2: !doc = true
```

So, for both requests the application thinks that the user doesn't exists and hence tries to create the document twice with the same key.

## How to solve it?

- Well, first of all, I've minimized the time between `findOne` and `save`. However, the problem is still happening on some occasions (only maybe 1/1000).
- I don't want to use upsert, since when creating the new user I'm also setting some other fields with default values. I think this would be tricky with upsert.
- Ideally I want to make sure that only one request can enter the processing logic at once (sort of like a mutex around a function call). However, I don't want to block the request call - so maybe there is some nice async lock utility I could use?

Example:

```
/* don't block, call the function when a lock can be acquired */
lock(function (done) {
    /* can only enter here one at a time */
    done(); /* <-- unlocks */
}
```

Or, am I approaching this in the wrong way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. **Do not use `.findOne()` and `.save()`** just **`.update()`** the object in the database directly.

MongoDB and "locking" ( in this way) are something that just *does not happen* and this is basically *by design*. You are not meant to:

1. Reserve a book
2. Take book from shelf
3. Write new paragraph to book
4. Return book to shelf
5. Un-Reserve book for others to use

This is a "great big **NO** in scaleable patterns.

So *instead* of doing that you just.

> *"Write new paragraph to book on shelf"*

And preferably

> *"Write new paragraph to book on shelf, where the current paragraph is what I expect it to be"*.

That should be a "clear" analogy.

So instead do:

```
User.update(
   { "user": 123 },
   { "$set": { "updated": new Date() } },
   function(err,numAffected) {
       // do something in callback
   }
);
```

Which "simply" just updates the current "updated" date at the time of the request that is made there and then.

Or better:

```
var updatedDate = new Date();

User.update(
   { "user": 123, "updated": { "$lt": updatedDate } },
   { "$set": { "updated": updatedDate } },
   function(err,numAffected) {
       // do something in callback
   }
);
```

Which wil not touch the object is the curren value of "updated" is "greater than" the value you want to set it to.

Pure logic.

Comment: Surely this won't work if the document doesn't exist yet. So, ``upsert`` needs to be specified. In that case how would I do "set these fields to these values for new documents" without overriding those fields for existing documents.

Comment: @pbergqvist Sure. That is valid. But I was mostly writing about the pure sentiment of "updating". If you **need** to create then you "upsert". But the question was posed as `.findOne()` and then `.save()`. So you don't `.findOne()` where nothing exists, now do you?

Comment: maybe I should have made it more clear in my question, but the creation of new documents is key to the problem I'm facing. So in that case I'm looking for how I could achieve setting default fields while using upsert.

Comment: actually, ``$setOnInsert`` might solve the problem using upsert

Comment: @pbergqvist Sure should. I've posted that a few times already. `$setOnInsert` only occurs on an upsert. But the `$lt` condition in the example also works for this simple case. Anyhow you asked about `.findOne()` and `.save()`. I answered about how this is the wrong approach for "concurrent" systems. That's my point.